# performs concatenation instead of addition javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script..

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var y=$("#text").val();
var z=10;
var x=y+z;
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
demoP.innerHTML="x=" + x;
}
</script>
```

It reads the value of a text-field and add with a value. But it performs concatenation instead of addition. How can I solve this problem.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var y=$("#text").val();
```

returns a string.

What you need to do is convert/coerce this result to a number using one of the following methods:

```
var y = parseInt($("#text").val(), 10);

var y = parseFloat($("#text").val()); //  returns a floating point number

var y = Number($("#text").val());

var y = +$("#text").val();
```

Comment: worked var y = Number($("#text").val());

Answer (score 1):

```
var y=parseInt( $("#text").val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the value of an input is text.

You need to convert it into numeric.

```
var x = +(y) + z;
```

`+(y)` will safely make it numeric, if it is a number.

Comment: Tried this. But not working...

Comment: I can't say why it isn't working. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WNwEQ/. In case the entry is not numeric it should throw a NaN

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var y=parseInt($("#text").val());
var z=10;
var x=y+z;
```

Answer (score 0):

An inputs value is always a string, and adding a string with a number will always end up as a string.

To solve it, convert the string to a number with either `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, depending on what the value is (integer or float), or just convert it to a Number type with a plus operator in front of it:

```
var y = +$("#text").val();
var z = 10;
var x = y+z;
```