# Even the most basic Javascript is failing on me - but WHY?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with some very basic Javascript here (not a big fan or expert in Javascript at all!), and I just cannot wrap my head around why this fails....

I have some very basic HTML markup:

```
Value 1: <input type="text" id="int1" /> <br />
Value 2: <input type="text" id="int2" /> <br /><br />

<input type="button" name="add" value="Add" onclick="add();" />
```

and then some Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onerror = unhandled;

function unhandled(msg, url, line) {
   alert('There was an unhandled exception');
}

function add() {
   alert($("#int1").val() + $("#int2").val());
}
</script>
```

From my (Pascal- and C#-based) understanding, the `add` method should read out the values from the input elements with ID's `int1` and `int2` and add those values and then show the result.

Seems basic and harmless enough......

But even if I do enter two valid integers (like 10 and 20) into those two textboxes, I keep getting an `There was an unhandled exception` and I just *cannot* understand what is going wrong here.

Can someone enlighten me??

Comment: That's not just Javascript, you are using some kind of library, which seems to be jQuery. Have you included that library?

Comment: The `unhandled` function takes parameters. Look at them. And please read [Debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: Get rid of the `onerror = unhandled;`, open up your browser's console (Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome) and navigate to the console tab, it will give you a nice error trace (line numbers and all). (If you want to keep it, set up a "dev mode" variable somewhere to toggle its usage.)

Comment: `alert()` isn't a debug tool :( don't use it like one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216422/performs-concatenation-instead-of-addition-javascript

Comment: When I try the code it works. Well, it probably doesn't give you the expected result as it concatenates the values, but it doesn't crash. http://jsfiddle.net/2dj4k/

Comment: Please study about adding an event listener with JavaScript. Inline JS should never be used.

Comment: @Guffa: ok, so if I want to do this with **plain** Javascript - how do I need to change it? (sorry, I really don't know JS well)

Comment: @marc_s: Instead of `$("#int1").val()` you would use `document.getElementById("int1").value`. The you would use `parseInt(document.getElementById("int1").value, 10)` to make it a numeric value. And the same for `int2` naturally.

Comment: @Guffa: thanks! Works like a charm now! JS keeps being a (dark & scary) mystery to me ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.val()` returns a string value. you need to convert both returned strings to numbers and then add the values.

try this

```
function add() {
    alert(parseFloat($('#int1').val()) + parseFloat($('#int2').val()));`
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: add is not a function in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few different issues going on here.

Firstly, if you're using jQuery, it would be best to use a click event instead of an inline function call.

Second, the values are returned as strings from the inputs, so you must convert them by using *parseInt()*

Also, your error handler is useless if you're not alerting the error message, the *msg* argument in this case.

```
onerror = unhandled;

function unhandled(msg, url, line) {
   alert(msg);
}

$("input[name=add]").click(function() {
   var int1 = parseInt($("#int1").val());
   var int2 = parseInt($("#int2").val());
   alert(int1 + int2);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bepJ/

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly, `.val()` will return a string. The addition operator won't add the numeric values of those strings, it will just concatenate the strings.

But that's not causing your exception. Get rid of the everything but the add function. It should work then.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add() {
       alert($("#int1").val() + $("#int2").val());
    }
</script>
```

This is, of course, assuming you included the jQuery library since that's where the $() function comes from.

Comment: `$('#int1').val()*1` or `Number($('#int1').val())` will handle the type casting... well, except for `NaN`.

Comment: I'm a parseInt() kinda guy myself ;)

Comment: @isick If it's an _Int_, I'm a `i | 0` kind of person. Bitwise operators invoking `ToInt32` ftw

Answer (score 1):

Try using binding onclick event instead writing it inline. 
I have made fiddle for you. Check it out

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/rkhadse_realeflow_com/FhL9g/7/

```
  <script>
function add() {
    var int1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("int1").value);
    var int2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("int2").value);
    alert(int1 + int2);
}
    </script>

  Value 1:
<input type="text" id="int1" />
<br />Value 2:
<input type="text" id="int2" />
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: @marc_s : check this fiddle out.. 
Plain JavaScript : http://jsfiddle.net/rkhadse_realeflow_com/FhL9g/7/

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you're using `$(..)` functions, be sure you're including jQuery on the page, before you use those functions.

Aside from that, I always have scope issues when I put my event handlers in HTML attributes. Try putting them in your code, which has the added benefit of being unobtrusive JavaScript (a new pattern for cleaner, more maintainable code).

Also, add an `id` to your button:

```
<input type="button" name="add" value="Add" id="myButton" />
```

Add event handler in code and remove `onclick` attribute from your button

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = add;
```